# Does $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let f be a twice differentiable function on R such that both $f'$ and $f''$
are strictly positive on R. Then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= \infty$.

I know the result is false and i can think of some example in my mind...but I can't get a concrete counterexample.

If this result is true please exaplain why? I hope it won't be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'$ is strictly positive, and increasing, then we have $f'(x)>k=f'(0)$ for all positive $x$. That means that, for positive $x$, $f(x)\ge g(x)=f(0)+kx$. We know that $g\to\infty$ as $x$ grows, so that's a proof.

Comment: But the answer is given as false http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2018/Files/GS2018_QP_MTH.pdf.  See question number 8

Comment: $f, f'$ are supposed to be striclty positive, not stricly increasing.

Comment: @Jonas, it's $f'$ and $f''$ that are strictly positive. That makes $f$ and $f'$ strictly increasing. Otherwise $\arctan x + 2$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: in the file you linked the case is that $f$ and $f''$ are strictly positive. Nothing about $f'$, which can (and in a counterexample will be) negative.

Comment: Yep f and f' are strictly increasing

Comment: Ups. Misread the problem. Sorry.

Comment: @CloudJR, the problem you wrote here, and the problem in the link you posted, are not the same. Yours has $f'$ strictly positive, but the linked problem does not.

Comment: If you want $f$ and $f''$ strictly positive, with $f$ not growing without bound, just use $f(x)=e^{-x}$

Comment: How did you give counter example so quickly

Comment: It's the obvious counterexample once you read the question correctly.

Comment: I just imagined a positive, decreasing, concave up function, and it looked like exponential decay :)

Comment: @wonko i like your answer ...lol

Comment: Thanks G Tony jacobs